# jquery Tablesorter fail/not sorting column with a content complex

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I Try to Make a Sorting Table with a some codes html but its not Work the sorting on some of columns..

This is the sample Table i Use..

```
<table id='resultados' class="tbinformes-data" >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 20px;">Descripcion</th>
            <th>Asunto</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 20px;" >Departamento</th>
            <th style="padding-right: 20px;">Adjunto</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
            {%for data in ARRDAT['DATA'] %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{loop.index}}</td>
              <td><a href="link_toPath/{{data.id}}" >{{data.name}}</a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" title="Ver nota" data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="abreNotaPopUp('{{ data.note_id }}')">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye text-primary"></i>
                </button> &nbsp;
                    {{data.descrip}}
                </td>
              <td>
               {{data.asunto}}
              </td>
              <td>{{data.departamento}}</td>
              <td> 
              <a href='{{ path('descarga_adjunto_nota', { 'idNota' :  data.note_id }) }}' class="btn btn-xs btn-default" title="Descargar Adjunto" data-toggle="tooltip">
                    <span class="fa fa-link text-primary"></span>
                 </a>&nbsp;
                {{data.adjunto}}
                </td>
              <td>{{data.fecha|date('d/m/Y H:i:s')}}</td>
            </tr> 
        {% endfor %}    
       </tbody>
      </table>
```

So the columns Like a "" links or Buttons or a Large Text doesn't sort...!!
the others Cols are Fine sorting with a short text ...

Comment: I have a Solution but i can't post the Answer, i try to make a usefull answer to others users..

Answer (score 0):

I think 3rd column is `<buttton>` tag and not `<buttom>` tag, so please correct it.

And to sort the values in a column which contains Links and buttons, you need to add custom parser as follows,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // add parser through the tablesorter addParser method 
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        // set a unique id 
        id: 'linksandButtons',
        is: function(s)
        {
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s)
        {
            // format your data for normalization 
            var textwithoutopeningTag = s.replace(new RegExp(/<.*?>/),"");
            var textwithoutclosingTag = textwithoutopeningTag.replace(new RegExp(/<.*?>/),"");
            return textwithoutclosingTag.trim();
        },
        // set type, either numeric or text
        type: 'text'
    }); 


    // Apply "links" parser to the appropriate column
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#resultados").tablesorter({
            headers: {
                1: {
                    sorter: 'linksandButtons'
                },
                2: {
                    sorter: 'linksandButtons'
                },
                5: {
                    sorter: 'linksandButtons'
                }
            }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have another solution but i can't post!! Thnx